# Joining MySQL tables with key value pairs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, key, aggregate-functions

I have a table structure as described below:

```
persons
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Bart |
| 2  | Lisa |
+----+------+

keys
+----+--------+
| id | key    |
+----+--------+
| 1  | gender |
| 2  | age    |
+----+--------+

values
+----+-----------+--------+--------+
| id | person_id | key_id | value  |
+----+-----------+--------+--------+
| 1  | 1         | 1      | male   |
| 2  | 1         | 2      | 10     |
| 3  | 2         | 1      | female |
| 4  | 2         | 2      | 8      |
+----+-----------+--------+--------+
```

And I would need to get result a table like this:

```
+-----------+------+--------+-----+
| person_id | name | gender | age |
+-----------+------+--------+-----+
| 1         | Bart | male   | 10  |
| 2         | Lisa | female | 8   |
+-----------+------+--------+-----+
```

I can achieve this by using LEFT JOINs, but that doesn't work dynamically.

I could make a PHP script that would generate the SQL, but there must be way to make a query that works dynamically.

Comment: The last sentence of @Prdp his answer are the best way to go. Read about [data normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to understand why and when you split columns to different tables.

Comment: SELECT *.values, key.keys, name.persons FROM values 
LEFT JOIN keys 
ON values.key_id = keys.id 
LEFT JOIN persons 
ON values.person_id = persons.id

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am having a similar situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44445013/pdo-normalizing-mysql-tables?noredirect=1#comment75888296_44445013

Answer (score 6):

`Conditional Aggregation` + `Join`

```
SELECT p.person_id,
       p.NAME,
       Max(CASE WHEN key_id = 1 THEN value END) AS Gender,
       Max(CASE WHEN key_id = 2 THEN value END) AS Age
FROM   VALUES v
       JOIN person p
         ON v.person_id = p.id
GROUP  BY p.person_id,
          p.NAME
```

Get rid of `Keys` and `Values` table and add two columns called `Age` and `Gender` in `Person` table itself

Comment: Thanks, however this still isn't completely dynamic solution.The reason I have seperate tables for keys and values is because this is used to generate a form, and the user must be able to add new keys. This is simplified, I actually have two other columns in keys, one for type and one for possible values. If the type is "dropdown" then the possible values must be in the other column