# pdo normalizing mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am rather new to Normalization. I understand the concept of how it organizes the tables but I fail to see how I can use the data to show up correctly.

I have 3 tables:

```
employees:
id  |  name
1     user1
2     user2
2     user3

shops:
shop_id  | shop
1          shop1
2          shop2
3          shop3
4          shop4
5          shop5

shop_employees:
shops_employees_id  |  employee_id  |  shop_id
1                      1               1
2                      1               2
3                      2               4
4                      3               3
5                      3               5
```

but I get:

```
user1 shop1
user1 shop2
user2 shop4
user3 shop3
user3 shop5
```

How can I get them in one row like:

```
user1 shop1 shop2
user2 shop4
user3 shop3 shop5
```

this is my code:

```
<?php

...

try
{
    $DB_con = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
    $DB_con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

class crud
{
    private $db;

    function __construct($DB_con)
    {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }


    public function getID($id)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array(":id"=>$id));
        $editRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $editRow;
    }


    public function dataview($query)
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
        {
            while($row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {

                ?>

                <tr>
                <td><?php print($row['id']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['name']); ?></td>
                <td><?php print($row['shop']); ?></td>

                <?php

            }
        }
        else
        {
            ?>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="8" class="text-center danger"> Nothing founds...</td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }

    }


}

$crud = new crud($DB_con);


?>


<table>


<?php

    $query = "

    SELECT emp.id,
           emp.name,
           sh.shop
    from employees AS emp 
         INNER JOIN shops_employees AS se ON (emp.id     = se.employee_id)
         INNER JOIN shops           AS sh ON (sh.shop_id = se.shop_id)
    ORDER BY emp.name,
             sh.shop;";




    $crud->dataview($query);

?>


</table>
```

Comment: You can't get them in one "row" like that because each row of your result set must have an identical number of columns, and this number must be fixed. You're trying to denormalize your data at the query level. That's futile. Instead do it in PHP by reorganizing the data-structures you're given.

Comment: Can you show me an example how you would do it in php, please?